# where to find kivy default pictures

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I guess kivy must have a lot of pictures already included such as

[image]

Probably there are even more such as a loudspeaker. Where can you find them and how can you use them in a kivy app?

Comment: You just want to show the images, or use them as buttons?

Comment: Yes use them as buttons. I just guessed, there must be a bunch of pictures inside kivy, but I do not know where or how to import them

Comment: There are not a bunch of pictures included. There is a default theme you can edit. Otherwise, just download or create an image, and use it as a button

Comment: I know how to use pictures. How could I use one of the included ones?